Using JS-Interpreter with Blockly - how can I access the module itself?
I'm very sorry in advance if this is a novice question, I simply couldn't understand the online resources.
I created a Blockly project using npx, and I want to add JS-Interpreter to it. I added the source files, included them in a <script> tag in index.html, but I can't access any functionality within index.js. How can I import the interpreter into the index.js file? Am I even supposed to use it inside this file? Most resources online don't show this project structure, instead importing Blockly using a <script> tag and writing the code inside index.html.
Many thanks!

What do you mean with JS-interpreter? Why would add a JS-interpreter to a script?

Sorry, I was referring to Neil Fraser's JS-Interpreter project which Google recommends for use with Blockly. I want to include it so I can execute the generated JS code from the blocks.

Can you share your code so far? It's harder to write an answer guessing your use case and starting from scratch. I assume this is the JS-interpreter you mean? (good idea to [edit] those details into the question). JS-interpreter docs show how to add script tags: https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html. They also offer a live demo you can cop the source from.

Alternatively, if you're using a build stage and npm, you can use the npm package for js-interpreter.

Tysm, I wasn't aware that it was available on NPM. I installed it through there and it worked, if anyone is still interested in the problem I could share the code.

Thanks, I'd still share the code for the benefit of future visitors.

As ggorlen pointed out, the library is available through NPM, and installing it through there solved the issue. If anyone is still interested in the problem I could provide more details. Many thanks!
